# Visual Studio Unit test crashes

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing

I suddenly get errors while running the unit test for C# program in visual studio.
I guess the error appears after I added the System.Numerics.Vectors NuGet package, howewert the test I run **does not use it yet**.
Before adding it, the test run was fine.
I get following error:

```
for more details on managing these settings.
[1/13/2018 6:37:32 PM Informational] Test Adapter for Google Test: Test discovery starting...
[1/13/2018 6:37:32 PM Error] ERROR: Exception while discovering tests: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at GoogleTestAdapter.DiaResolver.PeParser.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<ProcessImports>b__0(LoadedImage image)
   at GoogleTestAdapter.DiaResolver.PeParser.ParsePeFile(String executable, ILogger logger, Action`1 action)
   at GoogleTestAdapter.DiaResolver.PeParser.ProcessImports(String executable, ILogger logger, Func`2 predicate)
   at GoogleTestAdapter.DiaResolver.PeParser.FindImport(String executable, String import, StringComparison comparisonType, ILogger logger)
   at GoogleTestAdapter.GoogleTestDiscoverer.IsGoogleTestExecutable(String executable, String customRegex, ILogger logger)
   at GoogleTestAdapter.GoogleTestDiscoverer.<>c__DisplayClass6_0.<DiscoverTests>b__0()
   at GoogleTestAdapter.Settings.SettingsWrapper.ExecuteWithSettingsForExecutable(String executable, Action action, ILogger logger)
   at GoogleTestAdapter.GoogleTestDiscoverer.DiscoverTests(String executable, ITestFrameworkReporter reporter, SettingsWrapper settings, ILogger logger, IDiaResolverFactory diaResolverFactory)
   at GoogleTestAdapter.GoogleTestDiscoverer.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<DiscoverTests>b__1()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.WaitAll(Task[] tasks, Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at GoogleTestAdapter.Helpers.Utils.SpawnAndWait(Action[] actions, Int32 timeoutInMs)
   at GoogleTestAdapter.GoogleTestDiscoverer.DiscoverTests(IEnumerable`1 executables, ITestFrameworkReporter reporter)
   at GoogleTestAdapter.TestAdapter.TestDiscoverer.DiscoverTests(IEnumerable`1 executables, IDiscoveryContext discoveryContext, IMessageLogger logger, ITestCaseDiscoverySink discoverySink)
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at GoogleTestAdapter.DiaResolver.PeParser.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<ProcessImports>b__0(LoadedImage image)
   at GoogleTestAdapter.DiaResolver.PeParser.ParsePeFile(String executable, ILogger logger, Action`1 action)
   at GoogleTestAdapter.DiaResolver.PeParser.ProcessImports(String executable, ILogger logger, Func`2 predicate)
   at GoogleTestAdapter.DiaResolver.PeParser.FindImport(String executable, String import, StringComparison comparisonType, ILogger logger)
   at GoogleTestAdapter.GoogleTestDiscoverer.IsGoogleTestExecutable(String executable, String customRegex, ILogger logger)
   at GoogleTestAdapter.GoogleTestDiscoverer.<>c__DisplayClass6_0.<DiscoverTests>b__0()
   at GoogleTestAdapter.Settings.SettingsWrapper.ExecuteWithSettingsForExecutable(String executable, Action action, ILogger logger)
   at GoogleTestAdapter.GoogleTestDiscoverer.DiscoverTests(String executable, ITestFrameworkReporter reporter, SettingsWrapper settings, ILogger logger, IDiaResolverFactory diaResolverFactory)
   at GoogleTestAdapter.GoogleTestDiscoverer.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<DiscoverTests>b__1()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()<---
```

can someone give me advice pls?

To see it, it is enough to do :

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {

        Console.WriteLine("hello");
    }
}
```

Comment: please edit your question and include the test in question we need to be able to see what you are doing

Comment: sorry i dont want to post the test.
i just figured out what causes that: its Build-> Plattform Target -> 64x produces the error, while "any CPu" builds fine.
Howerer, i have 64x CPU, why do i have that?

Comment: The x86 unit test done want to rn tests bild for 64x somehow:
Test run will use DLL(s) built for framework Framework45 and platform X86. Following DLL(s) will not be part of run: 
Tests1.dll is built for Framework Framework45 and Platform X64.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee782531.aspx

Comment: Such should be reported to the extension authors directly, https://github.com/csoltenborn/GoogleTestAdapter